# Adding a selection provider to a view that contains only widgets?

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

Can we Add a selection provider to a view that contains only widgets?If so how What should be the setSelection's Parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on the kind of implementation that you have done. If you are using widgets as some kind of select-able entities in the view then you can provide setSelection implementations.

The `setSelection` takes an `ISelection` instance, and it can contain any kind of object. So for example if your view has a form, with many labels and editable fields, you might want to "set focus and scroll to" any of the fields depending on the situation from the outside programmatically. Your setSelection would receive an object (maybe just even an integer index) wrapped in a ISelection object. It would be up to the implementation of the setSelection to move focus to the specific control and scroll to it.